# Dynamic string matrix in C

Tags: c, memory, matrix, dynamic

I am having the next problem. I'm trying to create a dynamic matrix of strings which dimensions are defined by the user. The next code I made returns a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char ***pa = NULL;
    int rows, columns , max, i, j = 0;

    //Ask dimension
    puts("Type number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&columns);
    puts("Type number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    puts("Type max string length: ");
    scanf("%d",&max);

    //Allocate in memory
    ***pa = (char ***)malloc(rows * sizeof(char**));
    for(i=0;i<rows; i++){
        pa[i] = (char **)malloc(columns * sizeof(char*));
        for(j=0; i<columns;j++){
            pa[i][j] = (char)malloc((max+1)*sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    puts("Memory OK");

    //Fill the matrix
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        strncpy(pa[i][j] , "Hello world", max);
        for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
            strncpy(pa[i][j] , "Hello world", max); 
        }
    }

    //Shows the matrix
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        puts(pa[i][j]);
        for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
            puts(pa[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //Cleans the matrix
    free(pa);

    return 0;
}
```

I know I should check if the returned pointer by malloc is NULL but I didn't included it yet.
The program does not print this so the problem is in the malloc for's

```
puts("Memory OK");
```

How can I debug this so I could know what happend? Did I made a mistake while coding it?

Comment: `***pa = (char ***)malloc(rows * sizeof(char**));` should be `pa = malloc(rows * sizeof *pa);`.

Comment: Excuse me for the tag, I didnt't notice. I though every variable should be initialized, even pointers. Is it better to not set it to NULL?

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled and treat the warnings as errors.

Comment: 1) There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your code, nothing which can point to one or represent one. 2) You apparently want a 3D array. Why don't you use one? 3) Being a 3-star C programmer is not a compliment.

Comment: I know that in fact is a 3D array. Im trying to do it in this way as a personal execise. Sure there are other ways but I want to learn how to do it like that.

Comment: @mch it still doesn't work , now program crash.

Comment: You do not 0-terminate your arrays if `max` is smaller than `12` (`strlen("Hello world") + 1`.

Comment: @mch e.g. doing`pa[i][j][max+1] = "\0"` would null terminate the string?. Also, What problems can cause a not 0-terminate string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
pa[i][j] = (char)malloc((max+1)*sizeof(char));
```

into:

```
pa[i][j] = (char *)malloc((max+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Also, no need for the outer (first) `strncpy` in the `main`.

[EDIT]

Also, the first allocation line `***pa = ...` should be `pa = ...`. You want to assign an address to the pointer `pa`, not de-reference it (`***pa` de-references the pointer `pa` that has not been yet initialized).

Comment: [The `(char*)` cast shouldn't be there at all.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1679849)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Why that?

Comment: That was a link I posted.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage  Do not give references to wrong answers of low-qualified programmers.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi  He is just wrong along with the bad answer in the given reference.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Lol ok Vlad

Comment: @AhmadWabbi IIf something is allowed it does not mean that it should be done.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, given the immense amount of contribution [**unwind**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) made to the `C` tag, calling him "low-qualified" is not only wrong, it's downright ludicrous. You may not agree with him, but your reason is a non-argument based on nothing but an ad-hominem attack. In fact, this question demonstrates exactly why casting when you don't have to is a good way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @StoryTeller  I am sure that low-qualified programmers is much more than qualified programmers. Thus you are saying about the immense amount of low-qualified programmers. And I agree with you. They are indeed too many.:)

Comment: @StoryTeller As for arguments then you are not the first who asks me. I already answered such question many times. I have not a desire to answer  one thousand and one times.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you leverage c99 to the fullest, and allocate the entire matrix as a single block. You'll be reducing the fragmentation of your programs memory and making iteration over the matrix more cache friendly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    int rows, columns , max;

    puts("Type number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&columns);
    puts("Type number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    puts("Type max string length: ");
    scanf("%d",&max);

    char (*mat)[columns][max+1] = malloc(rows * columns * (max + 1));

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            strncpy(mat[i][j] , "Hello world", max); 
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
            puts(mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    free(mat);

    return 0;
}
```

Other added bonii:

1. Removes the complexity involved with allocating your memory. No more nested loops with `malloc`s
2. No need to loop for `free`ing the whole thing, just `free` the one pointer. You already do that, but in your case it leaks memory.

Cons:

1. May fail to allocate the entire block for large matrices. Here the fragmented approach may be better.

Comment: So In the way I am doing elements are not near each other in memory.  Are they?

Comment: @CarlosManrique They may be very close. But not contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to veryone for helping me to solve it. I've learned new things with you.
First of all, I changed this.

```
pa = malloc(rows * sizeof(char**));
for(i=0;i<rows; i++){
    pa[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(char*));
    for(j=0; j<columns;j++){//Here there was an i. That was totally wrong.
        pa[i][j] = malloc((max+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Now it works and allocates correctly the matrix into de memory.

Comment: So, you did what I suggested in my answer, but without the casting (even though you may have kept it). In SO, this is usually translated to an up-vote, as an expression of gratitude for those who spent time helping you. I am telling you this just because you are new here, no need to your up-vote anyway.

Comment: As you say I just registered in the page, Im still learning how this works. Excuse me if I made a mistake.

Comment: No problem, I knew that. I just wanted to draw your attention to it so that the others do not take it bad in the future. Good luck.